# What's the connection between Numeria (in Pathfinder) and Numenera?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, numenera

I've been playing the [Iron Gods](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Iron_Gods_(adventure_path)) adventure path for Pathfinder 1e. I've previously played [Numenera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numenera) (a Cypher system game). The settings are striking, and I'm wondering why they are so similar. Do they spring from a common source? Did the same people work on them? Or perhaps some other reason?

There are of course plenty of differences in the details, but the primae facia similarities include:

- Both settings blend high fantasy and science fiction. Numeria is a traditional high-fantasy setting where extraterrestrial ships crash landed, injecting sci-fi wierdness. Numenera is a far future campaign setting where technology is frequently interpretted as magic.
- The names (Numeria and Numenera) are pretty similar.
- Both have some vague geographical similarities: relatively barren landscapes punctuated by a relatively small technologically and socially advanced area (Torch in Numeria, the Steadfast in Numenera).

Comment: Note that Torch is not the only semi-advanced settlement in Numeria. There are several other cities, with Starfall being notable as the capital of the region.

Comment: I believe you mischaracterize Numenera a little. It's a post-post-apocalyptic re-exploration setting, where technology has become forgotten and can only be explained as magic.

Comment: "*The names (Numeria and Numenera) are pretty similar.*" are they? Numenera derives from the Latin root "numen" (vaguely used to mean "supernatural power" with "numen-era" alluding to "supernatural era" or "divine era"). I don't know exactly what the etymology of "Numeria" is but I think it's *not* "numen". Sounds more like the same root as "numerous". Just because two words share a syllable or two, doesn't really mean they are related.

Comment: For what it's worth, Numeria seems to predate Numenara. The former's first mention is in 2008, while the latter was kickstarted in 2013. Sean K Reynolds has worked on both Golarion and Numenera, but the latter only after it was launched for several years (2018 is the earliest I can find), and he left Paizo before the Numeria specific source book in 2014, so that's probably a red herring. My guess is just common inspiration, but so far I've really only found red-herrings or lack of concrete details.